# How to call simple ajax program in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I start learning Ajax in asp.net MVC 4. I want to create a very simple program based on the following scenario.

I want two textboxes on a form (FirstName, LastName) and a button, Whenever i write something in these textboxes, these values should assign to two labels (lblFristName, lblLastName) by using Ajax. So that page will not refresh.

How can i achieve the above functionality?. Please provide clear/simple code examples and no other site links, Thanks.

Following is the code that iam trying for:-

```
 @model MvcAppLearn.Models.Student

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "AjaxCall";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>AjaxCall</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AjaxCall", "Ajax", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "my-form" }))
    {

        @:FirstName @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName);
        @:FirstName @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LastName);

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    }

        <br />


    <div id ="result">


    </div>

    @section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">



        $(function () {

            $("#my-form").on("Submit", function (e) {

                //e.preventDefault();
                debugger

                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    succes: function (data) {
                        $("#result").html(data);
                    },

                        error: function () {
                            alert("Oh noes");
                        }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
        }
```

**Partial View**

```
@model MvcAppLearn.Models.Student

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AjaxCall";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h2>Ajax Partial View</h2>

<label>@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.FirstName)</label><br />
       @Html.Label(Model.LastName)

@*  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName)<br />
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LastName)*@
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult AjaxCall()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual ActionResult AjaxCall(Student model)
        {

            return PartialView("ajax_partial" , model);
        }
```

So above code take me to the partial view, but i want to live on that page where my textboxes are placed and at the same page i want to display these labels. Please correct if there is any mistake, thanks

Comment: AJAX if for invoking a controller method on the server. Sound like you can do this with javascipt/jquery. you need to post more detail including your html

Comment: So what not working. Are there errors in the browser console? Is your method being hit? Why have you commented out `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Yes i have commented out. Page run successfully with refreshing page. But i don't want to refresh the page using Ajax.

Comment: If you don't use `e.preventDefault();` then the form will submit. Add it back in so the default action does not fire.

Comment: If i comment or not result is same. See in my controller iam returning patial view, is it fine ? I have no idea where iam stuck.

Comment: Yes you should be returning a partial view.

Comment: Can you please test my code in sample mvc application and send back to me? i shall be very thankful to you....

Comment: I have done it, Problem was i write "s" as capital in 'submit' and missed 's' in last at ":success" function, Anyway thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something your view looks like,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.textbox1, new { id = "textbox1"})
<label id="label1"></label>
```

You can achieve this using simple jquery change/keyup event

```
 $('#textbox1').bind("change keyup", function() {
        $('#label1').val($('#textbox1').val())
    });
```

Comment: Iam trying to learn ajax in mvc. So i need solution according to ajax  method, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done it, Problem was i write "s" as capital in 'submit' and missed 's' in last at ":success" function. Following is the correct code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">



    $(function () {


        $("#my-form").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //debugger
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#result").html(data);
                },

                    error: function () {
                        alert("Oh noes");
                    }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```